# Orders tag error: order_status parameter

Tags: expresso-store, error, database-error

I've just updated to Store 2.0.4 and have come across the following error on a page using the orders tag with "order_status" parameter:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'order_status' in 'where clause'

select * from `exp_store_orders` where `site_id` = '1' and `order_completed_date` > 0 and `order_status` = 'new' and `member_id` = '1' order by `id` asc limit 100 offset 0

Filename: third_party/store/src/Store/Illuminate/CodeIgniterConnection.php

Line Number: 100
```

My orders tag looks like this:

```
{exp:store:orders member_id="CURRENT_USER" order_status="new" secure="yes"}
```

Has the parameter name changed in 2.0.4, or is this a bug? The documentation still shows the parameter as "order_status".

https://exp-resso.com/docs/orders_tag.html

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome kitsimons. For the record, Stack Exchange uses markdown so you indent code with 4 spaces (or click the {} button in the toolbar :)

Comment: Lovely, thank you Adrian, that's sorted it. And thanks for the heads up :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Store and will be fixed in the next version.

In the meantime, if you need a fix you can open `third_party/store/src/Store/Module.php` and around line 773 look for this:

```
$this->queryAndOrParam($query, 'order_status', ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('order_status'));
```

Change it to this:

```
$this->queryAndOrParam($query, 'order_status_name', ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('order_status'));
```

That should do it!

Comment: Not exactly the same usage, but related: in Store 2.1.0 the orders report suffers from the same error when filtered by status. Temporary fix, edit `third_party/store/src/Store/Service/ReportsService.php` line 368: $query->where('order_status', $status);
to $query->where('order_status_name', $status); line 411: ee()->db->where('order_status', $status);
to ee()->db->where('order_status_name', $status);

Comment: Hi Toby. This bug is identified and already fixed and will be rolled out very shortly in the 2.2 release. Also, just for the record, in the spirit of StackExchange any problems should be posted as a new question. Answers are reserved only for answering the original question.